# PHP Array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [slideritem] => 592
        [sliderbig] => 644
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [slideritem] => 593
        [sliderbig] => 645
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [slideritem] => 594
        [sliderbig] => 646
    )
```

slideritem is the id of an image that will be displayed and the slidebig is the image that will be linked to be displayed on a lightbox.

In other words i want the markup to be:

```
<a href="[sliderbig]"><img src="[slideritem]" /></a>
```

I pretty sure it's a simple foreach statement but i'm already on my 12th hour straight in front of the screen  :)

Comment: looking for the foreach statement that will create the markup.

Comment: If you can, take a break (maybe have a nap) and come back to this tomorrow. You've got all the ingredients prepared except the chef.

Comment: yeah that was the last bit. off of the weekend. have a good one and thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
foreach($theArray as $slider) {
    printf('<a href="%d.png"><img src="%d.png" alt="sliderimage"/></a>', 
            $slider['sliderbig'],
            $slider['slideritem']);
}
```

Take a break!

Comment: yeap. that will do. heh, amazing. have a good weekend ppl and thx :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo "<a href="{$item->sliderbig}"><img src="{$item->slideritem}" /></a>";
}
```

Comment: You need to escape the inner quotes if you want to use the {notation} but it will also raise "Trying to get Property of Non-Object" since the $item is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test($accum, $a) {
    return $accum . sprintf('<a href="url/to/%s">' .
        '<img src="url/to/%s" /></a>'."\n",
        htmlspecialchars($a['sliderbig']),
        htmlspecialchars($a['sliderbigitem']));
}

$output = array_reduce($array, 'test', '');
```